# Multiple variable limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I think $0$ is candidate for this limit, but I need help proving it:
$$\lim_{(x,y)->(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)(\ln(x^2+y^2)-1)$$

Also, I'm not sure how to approach this limit
$$\lim_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)->(0,\dots,0)}\frac{x_1\sin x_1+\cdots+x_n\sin x_n}{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the first question : $x^2+y^2=||(x,y)||_2^2$ and $(x,y)\to(0,0) \iff ||(x,y)||\to0$